# Calling JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs from Rust library fails with "cannot locate symbol "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs"

Tags: android, kotlin, rust

I'm trying to use the Rust library in my Android app.
To call the callback from a different thread I have to get the actual JavaVM reference.

```
        let jvm_ptr = Vec::with_capacity(1).as_mut_ptr();
        let count = null_mut();


        JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(jvm_ptr, 1, count); 
       //java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs" referenced by ....
```

I guess the problem is that some of the libraries are not loaded (libjvm, libdvm).
My question is how to load missed libraries?
Thank you.

Comment: You may want to consider using the [jni](https://docs.rs/jni/latest/jni/) crate

Answer (score 1):

On Android, you need to load the `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs` symbol dynamically, for example with the `libloading` crate.
The following code worked for me. Error handling is omitted in there.

```
pub type JniGetCreatedJavaVms = unsafe extern "system" fn(
    vmBuf: *mut *mut jni_sys::JavaVM,
    bufLen: jsize,
    nVMs: *mut jsize,
) -> jint;
pub const JNI_GET_JAVA_VMS_NAME: &[u8] = b"JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs";

[..]

let lib = libloading::os::unix::Library::this();
let get_created_java_vms: JniGetCreatedJavaVms = unsafe { 
 lib.get(JNI_GET_JAVA_VMS_NAME).unwrap() };
let mut created_java_vms: [*mut jni_sys::JavaVM; 1] = [ptr::null_mut() as *mut jni_sys::JavaVM];
let mut java_vms_count: i32 = 0;
unsafe {
    get_created_java_vms(created_java_vms.as_mut_ptr(), 1, &mut java_vms_count);
}
let jvm_ptr = *created_java_vms.first().unwrap();
let jvm = unsafe { JavaVM::from_raw(jvm_ptr) }.unwrap();
```

I'm using `libloading::os::unix::Library::this()` because the `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs` function is actually in `libnativehelper.so`, see https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1320.